# why this error occurs in opensuse as a host, that has 2 hypervisor on it?

Tags: qemu, virtualization, opensuse, libvirt

status of my VM in qemu/kvm take shutdown status, and my service stopped after this errors occuration.

this is result of journalctl:

```
hp4:/ #  journalctl -p err
Jan 02 17:00:35 hp4 kernel: [Firmware Bug]: the BIOS has corrupted hw-PMU resources (MSR 38d is 330)
Jan 02 17:00:35 hp4 kernel: i8042: Can't read CTR while initializing i8042
Jan 02 17:01:16 hp4 systemd[1]: Failed to start Self Monitoring and Reporting Technology (SMART) Daemon.
Jan 02 17:20:13 hp4 dolphin[4978]: inotify_add_watch(/home/vmq-hp4/configs/qemu) failed: (Permission denied)
Jan 02 17:20:13 hp4 konsole[5129]: kf.xmlgui: Shortcut for action  "" "Show SSH Manager" set with QAction::setShortcut()! Use KActionCollection::setDefaultShortcut(s) instead.
Jan 02 17:20:13 hp4 konsole[5129]: kf.xmlgui: Shortcut for action  "" "Show Quick Commands" set with QAction::setShortcut()! Use KActionCollection::setDefaultShortcut(s) instead.
Jan 02 17:20:13 hp4 konsole[5215]: kf.xmlgui: Shortcut for action  "" "Show SSH Manager" set with QAction::setShortcut()! Use KActionCollection::setDefaultShortcut(s) instead.
Jan 02 17:20:13 hp4 konsole[5215]: kf.xmlgui: Shortcut for action  "" "Show Quick Commands" set with QAction::setShortcut()! Use KActionCollection::setDefaultShortcut(s) instead.
Jan 02 17:20:13 hp4 kdesu[5394]: org.kde.kdesu: "No command specified."
Jan 02 17:20:14 hp4 konsole[5501]: kf.xmlgui: Shortcut for action  "" "Show SSH Manager" set with QAction::setShortcut()! Use KActionCollection::setDefaultShortcut(s) instead.
Jan 02 17:20:14 hp4 konsole[5501]: kf.xmlgui: Shortcut for action  "" "Show Quick Commands" set with QAction::setShortcut()! Use KActionCollection::setDefaultShortcut(s) instead.
Jan 02 17:20:14 hp4 konsole[5689]: kf.xmlgui: Shortcut for action  "" "Show SSH Manager" set with QAction::setShortcut()! Use KActionCollection::setDefaultShortcut(s) instead.
Jan 02 17:20:14 hp4 konsole[5689]: kf.xmlgui: Shortcut for action  "" "Show Quick Commands" set with QAction::setShortcut()! Use KActionCollection::setDefaultShortcut(s) instead.
Jan 02 17:20:15 hp4 dolphin[5579]: inotify_add_watch(/home/vmq-hp4/configs/qemu) failed: (Permission denied)
Jan 02 17:20:24 hp4 konsole[5292]: kf.xmlgui: Shortcut for action  "" "Show SSH Manager" set with QAction::setShortcut()! Use KActionCollection::setDefaultShortcut(s) instead.
Jan 02 17:20:24 hp4 konsole[5292]: kf.xmlgui: Shortcut for action  "" "Show Quick Commands" set with QAction::setShortcut()! Use KActionCollection::setDefaultShortcut(s) instead.
Jan 02 17:20:37 hp4 pulseaudio[4909]: GetManagedObjects() failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message>
Jan 02 17:20:45 hp4 libvirtd[5817]: error from service: Timeout was reached
Jan 02 17:20:45 hp4 libvirtd[5817]: End of file while reading data: Input/output error
Jan 02 17:20:54 hp4 libvirtd[5817]: authentication failed: access denied by policy
Jan 02 17:20:54 hp4 libvirtd[5817]: End of file while reading data: Input/output error
Jan 02 17:21:01 hp4 libvirtd[5817]: authentication failed: access denied by policy
Jan 02 17:21:01 hp4 libvirtd[5817]: End of file while reading data: Input/output error
Jan 02 17:21:11 hp4 libvirtd[5817]: authentication failed: access denied by policy
Jan 02 17:21:11 hp4 libvirtd[5817]: End of file while reading data: Input/output error
Jan 02 17:21:13 hp4 libvirtd[5817]: authentication failed: access denied by policy
Jan 02 17:21:13 hp4 libvirtd[5817]: End of file while reading data: Input/output error
Jan 02 17:24:06 hp4 libvirtd[6201]: Timed out during operation: cannot acquire state change lock (held by monitor=remoteDispatchDomainCreate)
Jan 02 17:24:07 hp4 libvirtd[6201]: Timed out during operation: cannot acquire state change lock (held by monitor=remoteDispatchDomainCreate)
Jan 02 17:24:16 hp4 libvirtd[6201]: Timed out during operation: cannot acquire state change lock (held by monitor=remoteDispatchDomainCreate)
```

to solve this problem, i just restart libvirted service, and try many time to startup machine. after that machines in qemu/kvm started